# Sqllite query convert timestamp to date

Tags: sqlite, date, timestamp, dbeaver

I'm working with DBeaver on Ubuntu Linux, and querying a sqlite database via a org.sqlite.JDBC driver.  In a table, a column called "event_date" is apparently of type

```
ABCevent_date(TIMESTAMP(10))
```

so when I query it I get a column of big long numbers like :

```
|event_date   |
|-------------|
|1430434800000|
|1430434800000|
|1430434800000|
|1430434800000|
|1430434800000|
|1433286000000|
|1433286000000|
```

I've tried lots of things using DATE, and DATETIME and STRFTIME but cannot get these to appear in the query results as a normal date like "2014-05-10", usually just get NULL.  How can I convert these numbers to dates?  Thx. J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates are unix epoch times with milliseconds.
You must divide `event_date` by 1000 to strip off the milliseconds and then use the function `date()` or `datetime()`:

```
SELECT date(event_date / 1000, 'unixepoch')
FROM ...
```